# heading breaking after every word for mobile devices

Tags: html, css

I have a `h6` in my app which is going to new line after every word for mobile devices.

Same is working for Desktops. I have not added any extra CSS for this.

the below code.

```
<td colspan="5" class="mobile-view-delivery"> <h6>Free Shipping Over Rs.1000/- Only Within India</h6> </td>
```

This is what I have.

Not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Please could you provide html code for coming to know the issue?

Comment: Show us your code so far

Comment: `<td colspan="5" class="mobile-view-delivery">
 <h6>Free Shipping Over Rs.1000/- Only Within India</h6>
 </td>`

This is what I have.